# android WebView fail to load a webpage that protected by Cloudflare

Tags: android, android-webview, cloudflare

I am developing an android application.
There is a webview in my app, it will load a webpage.

```
    webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36 SECSSOBrowserChrome");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("xxxx.html");
```

I tested with `https://www.google.com`, the webView worked normally.
But it failed to load xxx.html ( this site is protected by Cloudflare)

I added WebViewClient like this

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    KLog.d(TAG, "onPageStarted " + url);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                    KLog.d(TAG, "host =" + request.getUrl().toString());
                    view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    KLog.d(TAG, "onPageFinished " + url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                    KLog.d(TAG,"onReceivedError " + error.getDescription() + "Error code = " + error.getErrorCode());
                }
            });
```

But public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) { never call.

After waiting for a long time, I get this image

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12DmOGWNqKcq5IsMiQEApmtnvequOIxqD/view?usp=drivesdk

Could you help me to use android WebView to load this page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you probably have to enable Javascript in WebView also

Comment: I added : webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); But it doesn't work

Comment: Also consider adjusting security settings: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/android-system-webview-issue-with-some-sites/484530

Answer (score 0):

In the [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

> Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled
>   by default.

To enable **HTTP** based URLs in the app(not recommended) add below code in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the `application` tag

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: I already added it in android manifest, but it doesn't take effect

Comment: @Zappy.Mans just set the [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) and override the `onReceivedError` method. It will give you the error why the weblink is not working

Comment: This dumpstate log for this problem https://drive.google.com/file/d/11JeO2-W9i5pL-VWK8KfY5qQRJmM9_hfQ/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I added webViewClient and void onPageStarted never call

Comment: @Zappy.Mans override the onReceivedError method.

Comment: Yes. I did ( as you can see as source code above), I didn't get any log with that method

Comment: @Zappy.Mans override the `onReceivedSslError` method as well. see if you got something

Comment: I didn't get onReceivedSslError but I got this " onReceivedHttpError errorResponse.getEncoding() = utf-8 errorResponse.getMimeType()= text/html+ errorResponse.getReasonPhrase()= Origin Time-out"

Comment: @Zappy.Mans The 503 Service Unavailable error is an HTTP status code that means the website's server is simply not available right now

Comment: But we can open it in Google chrome app or Facebook messenger

Comment: I got this image after long time of waiting : https://drive.google.com/file/d/12DmOGWNqKcq5IsMiQEApmtnvequOIxqD/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @Zappy.Mans try removing the agent string you're setting

Answer (score 0):

It is because the server you are trying to access is not secure i.e it is using HTTP (not HTTPS).

Android P uses HTTPS by default. What this means is that if you are using unencrypted HTTP requests in your app, the app will work fine in all versions of Android except Android P.

To avoid this security, try below changes in your app code.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                    ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and in res/xml add file named : `network_security_config.xml`

in `network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        //  Add host of your URL in below line. 
        //   ie. if url is  "https://www.google.com/search?source=...."
        //   then just add "www.google.com"
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.myanmartvchannel.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: I just have added your suggestion, But It doesn't work

Comment: I am testing on android P

Comment: I posted some error log in the post. Is it enough ?

Comment: yes. It works normally in google chrome and Facebook messenger also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199598/discussion-between-dhaval-asodariya-and-zappy-mans).