# How can I fix this android WebView problem?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` to  `AndroidManifest.xml.`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>-->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is `MainActivity.java`

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBlockNetworkImage(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        Activity activity = this;
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Welcome", true);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
                mProgressDialog.show();

                webView.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }

        };
        webView.setWebViewClient(client);
        webView.loadUrl("http://xxxxxx.com/#/"); //Sorry i cant tell you :(

        setContentView(webView);
    }

}
```

And I have done some research on this problem...

so I also have put this `network_security_config.xml` file in `res/xml/`

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <!--<domain includeSubdomains="true">http://xxxxxxxx.com</domain>-->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://www.smarterasp.net</domain>

    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

but when I testing the app, it just working on version 7.1.1 (API 25)...

else, if i testing on android 8/9 version, it would be showing an error page or white screen

could anyone help?

Comment: What is the URL?

Comment: What specifically is the problem?

Comment: You just need to pass domain in `network_security_config.xml` file. e.g. `<domain includeSubdomains="true">www.smarterasp.net</domain>` So remove 'http://' from that.

Comment: @RahulKhurana the URL is cloud hosting by SmarterASP.NET, and the service is using HTTP

Comment: Try giving `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the `application` tag and remove the `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` line

Comment: @JoxTraex sorry for not clearly, the problem is the app not working on the lower/ higher version besides 7.1.1

Comment: @RahulKhurana I following your code, but the page return to error page this time... do I need to give you my event log?

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please be more explicit on what you are seeing.

Comment: how exactly is it not working? Does it crash? give wrong result? does not give result at all? *not working* is too broad, please be more specific.

Comment: @RahulKhurana E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(335)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: Where are you receiving this error? inside `onReceivedError` method?

Comment: @JoxTraex um...it means showing a blank page or white screen, sorry for still not clearly :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57985023/11555065)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android P requires HTTPS by default. What this means is that if you are using unencrypted HTTP requests in your app, the app will work fine in all lower versions than Android P.

To avoid this security exception, try below changes in your `network_security_config.xml` file.

**network_security_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        //  Add host of your download URL in below line. 
        //   ie. if url is  "https://www.google.com/search?source=...."
        //   then just add "www.google.com"
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.smarterasp.net</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Thank you! But now the error page/ blank page change to white screen... there's no anything else to show, what can I do?

Comment: Please wait for some times, may be your website taking time to load views. Because I have checked your code with my emulator. And it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code  to resolve this error :  Change **http://www.smarterasp.net** to **smarterasp.net**

> network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">

        <domain includeSubdomains="true">youtube.com</domain>
       <domain includeSubdomains="true">smarterasp.net</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

> Manifest

add These two lines

```
<application
      ..
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
       ..>
```

Comment: I see your point, thank you! But now the page change to display a white screen... do you know what is going on?